# Leaflet Geoman - How to add custom properties to layer / geojson on Geoman pm:create

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-geoman

I need to add a name and ID to the properties of a GeoJSON object when drawing a shape with Leaflet Geoman.

I'm writing the layers to a custom layer group:

```
map.pm.setGlobalOptions({
    layerGroup: stand_geojson_layer
});
```

I can successfully convert the drawn layer into GeoSON and console log it out. And even add to the properties in the resulting feature.

```
map.on('pm:create', (e) => {
    var layer = e.layer;
    var feature = layer.toGeoJSON();
    feature.properties.name = 'Test Name';
    console.log(feature);
});
```

The problem is that those properties aren't actually written to the layer it seems because when I get the whole FeatureSet into GeoJson the properties aren't there. I need to either add the properties to the layer itself before converting to GeoJSON or save / convert the added properties back into the layer somehow.

```
console.log(stand_geojson_layer.toGeoJSON());
```

Could anyone help as to how to get the properties into the layer or write them back?